# drf-yasg, easier way to see only certain end points?

Tags: django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

We have many apps and endpoints and its easier to expose certain endpoints to clients through yasg when we work on certain features.

Currently I'm defining separate urlpatterns for swagger in each app and aggregate it from upper url .

Do the following in each app (to selectively include endpoints)

```
 router_swagger.register(r'user_coupons', UserCouponViewSet)
 router_swagger.register(r'coupons', CouponViewSet)

 urlpatterns_swagger = [
     url(r'^rest_api/', include(router_swagger.urls)),
 ]
```

And aggregate the urlpatterns from somewhere else

```
swagger_urlpatterns = [                                                                                                                                       
]


from review.urls import urlpatterns_swagger as s1                                                                                                             
swagger_urlpatterns += s1                                                                                                                                     
from saleor.promotion.urls import urlpatterns_swagger as s2                                                                                                   
swagger_urlpatterns += s2

schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
        title="2019_09",
        default_version='v1',
    ),
    public=True,
    patterns=swagger_urlpatterns,
    permission_classes=[permissions.IsAdminUser],
)


urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^swagger/$', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),

]
```

It works but its somewhat tedious, wonder if there's a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

`drf-yasg` follows the same pattern as DRF(https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/) in implementing `get_schema_view`.

You could move the swagger file generation into a separate file and import all patterns into that file similar like this:

```
schema_view = get_schema_view(
    openapi.Info(
        title="API",
        default_version="v4",
        description="Some endpoints",
        contact=openapi.Contact(email="contact@snippets.local"),
        license=openapi.License(name="BSD License"),
    ),
    public=True,
    patterns=s1+s2+s3
)

urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^swagger/$', schema_view.with_ui('swagger', cache_timeout=0), name='schema-swagger-ui'),

]
```